# JQuery find HTML item and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a kinda specific problem. I have got a Webpage where it is possible to choose the amount of results to be shown. I did this with some buttons and a span for the active / chosen amount. Now I need to implement the ajax request for this and therefore I need to find out which amount is currently chosen and after the client picked another amount I need to update the HTML part, so the HTML part is always highlighting the current Amount. My Question is: How can I get the current data ID and how can I replace only this HTML Line when the button is active.

My HTML:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span>Show orders</span>
    <a href="" data-id="25">25</a>
    <span class="active" data-id="50">50</span>
    <a href="" data-id="75">75</a>
    <a href="" data-id="100">100</a>
    <a href="" data-id="125">125</a>
    <a href="" data-id="150">150</a>
    <a href="" data-id="1000">All</a>
</div>
```

My JQuery Guess to get the current Amount:

```
var selectedAmount = $( ".pagination" ).find ( ".active" ).data( "id" );
```

My JQuery Event to replace the  buttons with the  element and the other way round:

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Replace the old highlighted amountbutton with <a href> tag
    // And replace the old <a href> tag with the "highlighted" span button
});
```

Comment: do you want this to happen on click of selecting the amount? And, do you just want to hide the other amounts so that they can be reset? So the user can select a different amount?

Comment: I wanted it like Paul Rob did in his example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/nkhiD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selectedAmount` retrieval looks good. You could simplify it, though:

```
var selectedAmount = $( ".pagination .active" ).data( "id" );
```

As for the latter:

```
$('.pagination').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // Replace the old highlighted amountbutton with <a href> tag

    $('.pagination .active').replaceWith(
      function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var id = el.data('id');
        var txt = el.text();

        var a = $('<a>').text(txt).data('id', id).attr('href', '#');
        return a;
      }
    );

    // And replace the old <a href> tag with the "highlighted" span button
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var sp = $('<span class="active"></span>').text(txt).data('id', id);
    $(this).replaceWith(sp);

});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/nkhiD

Comment: Hm the Jquery effect, which should also prevent the default Action (visiting the a href link), doesn't work after there is created that new element. (Try clicking twice on the same Button/Link 50->100->50)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like **[replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)**:

```
$("button").replaceWith( "<a href='#'>Link</a>" );
```

I don't know exactly what you want to replace, so this is just an example, if you'd provide a fiddle, I can help you better.

Comment: I knew this function already, but I have problems to get the right item. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like, maybe this helps to understand my problem: http://puu.sh/b2fwb/a3efb3f529.png

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this with the target of the event.

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function(event)
{
   event.preventDefault();
   var newAmount= $(event.target).data('id'); 
   var selectedAmount =$( ".pagination .active" ).data( "id" );
 //You should be able to use replacewith or Append to figure out the rest


});
```